# Scan and print using android device

Tags: android

I have developed an application in which I have the facility to scan QR codes. I would like to print this scanned data to a network printer.

I had searched through the web and I couldn't find any source code for the same. Some solution I got was to use Google cloud print & some applications like PrintShare.

All I want is to develop the application that locates the printers connected to the WiFi network to which my android device is connected and prints the scanned data. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

No source code, but a well-put together guide is available at http://frank.zinepal.com/printing-directly-to-a-network-printer